# Makefiles with multiple targets: MAKECMDGOALS preferential treatment

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I was experimenting with Makefiles, specifically with Makefile rules containing more than one **target**

Consider this Makefile:

```
x := $(MAKECMDGOALS)
y := Whatever

dummy $(y) $(x) :
    @echo target: $@
```

Here, a simple `make` invocation outputs `target: dummy`, but a `make xyz` outputs `target: xyz`. Why does this happen? Is there something special with the MAKECMDGOALS variable? Why is variable x being treated 'with more importance' compared to y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would it have anything to do with `MAKECMDGOALS`?  It's just normal behavior.

Run this makefile, which doesn't use `MAKECMDGOALS` or variables at all, and you'll see the same result:

```
dummy Whatever xyz:
        @echo target: $@
```

It's because the default target for make if you don't give any goals on the command line is the first one, which in this case is `dummy`.  If you do give a goal (such as `make xyz`) then that's the target that will be built.

Comment: Ahh.. that makes sense. I was thinking waay too much about this problem